# Creating a custom SignInManager in Asp.Net Core 3 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to create a custom class for my SignInManager, so I've created a class that inherts from `SignInManager<>` as follows:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public ApplicationSignInManager(
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> logger,
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider
        )
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemeProvider)
    {
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
        _dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
    }
}
```

and then I've added it in the services configuration in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(configure =>
{
    configure.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters += " ";
}).AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
  .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The problem is that the default `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` cannot be casted to a `ApplicationSignInManager`, so I get this error when accessing a page in whose controller the manager is injected:

> *InvalidCastException:* Unable to cast object of type **'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Socialize.Data.ApplicationUser]'** to type **'Socialize.Utilities.Identity.ApplicationSignInManager'**.

Comment: What is your controller code? Fail to reproduce your issue. You need to inject `ApplicationSignInManager` instead of `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>`.

Comment: I had already injected `ApplicationSIgnInManager`. It was fixed by your other answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your issue is caused by that you register `AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()` before `.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)`.

For [AddDefaultUI](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/2c9e1940204837bcd425e8f4488bf2564434b357/src/UI/IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.cs#L52), it will call [builder.AddSignInManager();](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/Identity/IdentityBuilderExtensions.cs#L49) which will register the `typeof(SignInManager<>).MakeGenericType(builder.UserType)` and will override your previous settings.

Try Code below:

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()                
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

Comment: This worked for me without having to Inject ApplicationSignInManager into my controllers.  They still worked fine with the standard SignInManager injected.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Core 6

```
 public ApplicationSignInManager(
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser> claimsFactory,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<SignInManager<IdentityUser>> logger,
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
            IUserConfirmation<IdentityUser> iUserConfirmation
            )
            :base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemeProvider, iUserConfirmation)
    {
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this resource, you can use your own user tables without identity tables (AspNet*).

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers/sample/CustomIdentityProviderSample