# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync keep return me null object refrence

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

in my controller i use model to login these work fine and the model is give me the correct data 
when i log in to the account gives me null object reference

these is my model

```
    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        //[Display(Name = "Email")]

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

and my action here

```
public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager { 
   get { return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>(); 
   } 
   private set { _signInManager = value; } 
}

public async Task<ActionResult> LoginUser(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
       {
           if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               return View(model);
           }
           var user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);

           var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
           switch (result)
           {
               case SignInStatus.Success:
                   return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
               case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                   return View("Lockout");
               case SignInStatus.Failure:
               default:
                   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                   return View(model);
           }
       }
```

and here is the configration

```
 public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }
        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var d = new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
```

[and here the error in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqjvS.jpg)

and these my startup class that is which i configure the identity

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Baity.Startup))]

namespace Baity
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

           ConfigureAuth(app);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you find which variable is null and could you show your startup configureServices in which you register the identity ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230614/creating-a-custom-signinmanager-in-asp-net-core-3-identity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i  found the answer for my question is that in the identity configration and that's why it was not working for me

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the following line works

```
var user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);
```

Then it means that the `SignInManager` is not initialized in your controller.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

If you share your initialization code for the `SignInManager` we can help you more.

To get the manager in `Identity.Config.cs`

```
public static void RegisterAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   // Initialize the creation
   app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

}
```

And in startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup), "Configuration")]    
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is my initialization of sign in manager  ``` public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _signInManager = value;
            }
        }```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252251/asp-net-webapi-owin-why-would-request-getowincontext-return-null or share your startup file to check configuration.

Comment: here is my startup class `public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

        }
        
    }`

Comment: Have you added the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package and the `assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TestMVC5.Startup))]` in your startup?

Comment: yes i added it `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Baity.Startup))]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207056/discussion-between-ahmed-mehany-and-athanasios-kataras).

Comment: check the update i give you the configration class of signin manager

Answer (score 0):

What I figure out was that `_signInManager = signInManager;` was missing in the constructor of the Controller class so double check that.

```
 private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

 public (AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
 {
     //this was the issue as it was missing so add it should work 
       _signInManager = signInManager;
 }
```